# Swift Generics - Returning Subclasses of Generic Class

Tags: swift, generics

I'm looking to return any number of subclasses of a generic class in a single method but am unsure of how to format the function in order to do so. Below is a sample playground of my issue.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCellData {

}

class SubTableViewCellData: TableViewCellData {

}

protocol ClassProtocol {
    associatedtype DataType: TableViewCellData
}

class SuperDataClass {

}

class SubDataClass: SuperDataClass {

}

class SuperClass<T: SuperDataClass>: UITableViewCell, ClassProtocol {
    typealias DataType = TableViewCellData

}

class SubClass: SuperClass<SubDataClass> {
    typealias DataType = SubTableViewCellData
}

class Example {
    func test<T: SuperDataClass>(object: SuperClass<T>) {
        print(object)
    }

    func returnType() -> SuperClass<SuperDataClass>.Type? {
        var objectToReturn: SuperClass<SuperDataClass>.Type?
        if true {
            objectToReturn = SuperClass<SuperDataClass>.self
        } else {
            objectToReturn = SubClass.self
        }
        return objectToReturn
    }
}

let object = SubClass()
Example().test(object: object)

if let object2 = Example().returnType() {
    print(object2)
}
```

The code above will not run in a playground, you will see an error pointing to line 42 `objectToReturn = SubClass.self` because `error: cannot assign value of type 'SubClass.Type' to type 'SuperClass<SuperDataClass>.Type?'`.  Is there a way to change the object type to expect the generic and any subclass version of the generic?

Comment: I can not understand the task. What do you need to get in the end? Number?

Comment: I just need object2 to be a Subclass Type, but also be able to return a SuperClass type without a compile error for each.

Comment: I've updated the example to hopefully add some more clarity to my issue.